# Combining selected items from different lists into a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, genetic-programming

I have the following program:

```
random_pool=[[[0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1], [0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1], [0, 3], [3], [1]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0], [2, 2], [4], [2]],
 [[2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1], [3], [3]]]

binary_list=[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

def GeneratePopulation(random_pool, binary_list):
    individual = []
    population = []
    for gene in range(0, len(binary_list)):
        gene=binary_list[gene]
        for game in range (0, len(random_pool)):
            fitness=random_pool[game][2]
            counter=random_pool[game][3]
            individual=[gene,fitness,counter]
            population.append(individual)
    return(population)
```

With the output:

```
[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4], [2]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [3]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4], [2]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [3]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [3], [3]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1], [0]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [1]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]
```

My objective is to combine the elements gene (binary vector), from the binary_list with the last two elements of each item in the random_pool list, so the correct outcome would be:

```
[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]]
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]
```

I know there is something wrong with the loops, but I tried many things already and I couldn't get the result I wanted. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong or hot to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the version of your function that will give the expected results:

```
def GeneratePopulation(random_pool, binary_list):
    individual = []
    population = []
    for ind in range(0,len(binary_list)):
       fitness = random_pool[ind][2]
       counter = random_pool[ind][3]
       gene = binary_list[ind]
       individual=[gene,fitness,counter]
       population.append(individual)
     return(population)
```

In your original code the loop iterates ones through `random_pool` for every element in `binary_list` - that was not necessary and produced the repeated outcome.

Note that the variables `fitness`, `counter`, and `individual` are redundant here - you could achieve the same result without creating them. Do you need them for something else?

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, great! About the variables, I am naming them so I know which one is what during the program steps but on a second thought, I might delete them now, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked :) Yes, better avoid redundant variables like this, among others they create a false impression of being use somewhere. In that case you can simply pack the loop into one line `population.append([binary_list[ind],random_pool[ind][2],random_pool[ind][3]])`.

Comment: @skrx true, my personal choice is to keep only variables that are used and comment what is what in one line. But it's personal, you have a point there.

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic solution would be to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists, so that you can iterate over the `random_pool` and `binary_list` at the same time and don't have to use indexes.

You can also unpack the pool in this way: `*_, fitness, counter = pool`. The `*_` will unpack the first items into the variable `_` which is often used for unneeded values, and the last two are unpacked into the variables `fitness` and `counter`.

```
def generate_population(random_pool, binary_list):
    population = []
    for pool, gene in zip(random_pool, binary_list):
        *_, fitness, counter = pool  # Unpack the pool. Ignore the first two items.
        population.append([gene, fitness, counter])
    return population
```

With a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) or a generator expression, you can reduce the function even more.

```
def generate_population(random_pool, binary_list):
    return [[gene, fitness, counter]
            for (*_, fitness, counter), gene in zip(random_pool, binary_list)]
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I recommend watching Ned Batchelder's presentation ["Loop like a native: while, for, iterators, generators"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o).